# R boxplot title outlier

Tags: r, visualization, title, boxplot

I try to make a good Boxplot. As you can see in the picture, to get a clear visualization, it is necessary to "zoom in" into the biggest part of the data. 
I did this with the ylim option.

As you can see in the picture below I created an main title, the outliers are going through the title and that is the problem.

I think I could solve the problem by deleting the outliers in the original data, but I was wondering if it is possible to cut the "boxplotline" by 0.10, so the boxplot stays in the figure.

My code so far:

```
 boxplot (genergy$Measurevalue, ylim= c(0,0.1), ylab = "Measured Value", 
     main="Boxplot Measured Value", col = "red")
```

[image: Boxplot]

UPDATE: 
@Twitch_City: I don't think that use another ylim is the solution. For example:

```
boxplot (genergy$Measurevalue, ylim= c(0,0.50), ylab = "Measured Value", 
     main="Boxplot Measured Value", col = "red")
```

[image]

@akash87, sure. The data is:

[image]

Comment: Could you attach some data?

Comment: I am not sure why the outliers are appearing as a line?  They should be dots... If there are so many of them that the dots are appearing as a line, you should set the ylim to at least 0.12 to give them room on the plot.  Just removing them from the dataset is not an appropriate solution.

Comment: I updated my question (and answered your questions), hopefully we will solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `outline=FALSE` to avoid plotting the outliers completely. You could then provide data about the outliers separately (for example, using `fivenum` or other summary).

Here's an example using random data generated from a chi-squared distribution with df=3; the data are quite positively skewed, as your data seem to be. Save the boxplot stats to obtain info on the outliers.

```
N=500000
dat <- rchisq(N, 3)
dat.box <- boxplot(dat, cex=.5, outline=F, las=1)
cat(fivenum(dat.box$out))
```

Another alternative is to plot a kernel density curve and add lines corresponding to the desired quantiles. As below:

```
plot(density(dat), las=1)
abline(v=median(dat), col='black')
abline(v=quantile(dat, .25), lty=3, col='red')
abline(v=quantile(dat, .75), lty=3, col='red')
```